# R - vioplot, how read in columns from my data frame to be plotted?

Tags: r

Forgive the simplicity of my question, I am very, very new to R and have found that the guides I am reading are really not getting to the point about how to do something this simple (perhaps they are assuming I should know this already?).

Anyhow, I am trying to use vioplot to plot the distributions of data in three columns. One plot per column of my data file. The data file has already been read in with read.table.

Ignore the df[names(df)=="Fst_ceu_mkk"] parts here as I am aware that this doesn't work (I found it in a guide). Could anyone tell me what to use in their stead to read the data from the columns named? They are the 3rd, 4th and 5th columns in the file.

```
library(vioplot)
x1 <- df[names(df)=="Fst_ceu_mkk"]
x2 <- df[names(df)=="Fst_ceu_yri"]
x3 <- df[names(df)=="Fst_mkk_yri"]
vioplot(x1, x2, x3, names=c("CEU/MKK", "CEU/YRI", "MKK/YRI"),
   col="gold")
title("Genome-Wide FST Distribution by Population Pair")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the names of the columns in your data frame, but a general solution might be:

```
vioplot(df[,colnames(df)[3]], df[,colnames(df)[4]], df[,colnames(df)[5]])
```